# Slick Slider – change contents based on current slide data-index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following code for [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), which changes the content below based on the current slide data-index. I just wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it?

http://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/JYyjew

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var elSlide = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]);
    var dataIndex = elSlide.data('index');

  $('.content').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('id') == dataIndex) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }  
  });

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would combine the two lines where you get the `dataIndex`, rename that to `dataId` to be consistent with the HTML element, and replace the loop by hiding everything, and then showing the correct element by finding it with a jQuery selector:

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var dataId = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).data('index');  
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content[data-id=' + dataId + ']').show();    
});
```

I also noticed that looking up `dataId` is superfluous, since it is simply the value of `currentSlide` plus one.  So you could also make this change and retain the same behavior:

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){   
  $('.content').hide();
  $('.content[data-id=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great improvement Jonah. There was one thing that  I didn't see yesterday – on page load all contents are visible (I only want to show content one on page load). 
To modify this I added the following CSS:

`.two, .three, .four, .five {
  display:none;
}`

There is a slight odd behaviour that the page jumps up and down on slide change, unless this is just my screen height setup. Is CSS the way to go with this?

Comment: I tried in chrome and safari on my mac, and didn't see any page jump.  What browser are you using?

Comment: oh, maybe it's just my screen height. I'm on a macbook using Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.101).  What do you think about using CSS to hide the content? It works, but is it the best way.

Comment: Another option would be to have only a single div for the content, and dynamically update its text, the same way you are dynamically updating the current slider.  I think I'd prefer  this approach.

Comment: That sounds good, however the content will be dynamic and pulled in via other protocol.

Answer (score 1):

*I* can't see too many ways to improve this, but I have a few small changes you could make:

> ```
> $('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
>     var elSlide = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]);
>     var dataIndex = elSlide.data('index');
>
>   $('.content').each(function(){
>     if ($(this).data('id') == dataIndex) {
>       $(this).show();
>     } else {
>       $(this).hide();
>     }  
>   });
>
> });
> ```

The show/hide loop can be simplified to a ternary statement:

> ```
>   $('.content').each(function(){
>     if ($(this).data('id') == dataIndex) {
>       $(this).show();
>     } else {
>       $(this).hide();
>     }  
>   });
> ```

which would look like this:

```
  $('.content').each(function(){
    $(this).data('id') == dataIndex ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();  
  });
```

The other change I could suggest is *maybe* removing the `nextSlide` parameter as it is superfluous and unused.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks Quill. Both your answers are very good and improved my code. There is one thing I missed though – on page load, all contents are visible (only content one should be visible). I added the CSS `.two, .three, .four, .five {
  display:none;
}`

There is a slight odd behaviour that the page jumps up and down on slide change, unless this is just my screen height setup. Can you think of a better way to do this?